# Changing the value of a Javascript variable with user input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a weather site. I want to get the user input into a variable that changes the current city. Hope someone of you can help me.

```js
var userInput = "London";

function changeValue() {
  userInput = document.getElementById("user_Input").value;
  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = document.getElementById("user_Input").value;
}

window.onload = function() {

var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=";
var units = "&units=metric";
var url2 = api + userInput + units + APPID;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        
        var iconCode = myObj.list[0].weather[0].id;
        var directions = myObj.list[0].deg;

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            
            document.getElementById("day" + i).innerHTML =  Math.round(myObj.list[i].temp.day) + "°";
            document.getElementById("icon" + i).src = "sl_line/" + iconCode + ".svg";
            document.getElementById("wota" + i).innerHTML = wochentag[day.getDay()+i+1];
            document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = Math.round(myObj.list[0].humidity);
            document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = myObj.list[0].speed + " m/s";
            document.getElementById("direction").innerHTML = directions;
        }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url2, true);
xmlhttp.send();
};
```

```html
<article>
  <input id="user_Input" type="text" placeholder="Ortsuchen...">
  <button id="submit" onclick="changeValue()">Submit</button>
  <span id="location">Unknown</span>
</article>
<section>
      <div>
          <div><span id="day0" class="ml:.25r fs:6r">0</span></div>
          <div><span id="wochentage">0</span></div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <img id="icon0">
      </div>
      <div>
          <span id="wind">0</span><span id="direction"></span><span></span>
      </div>
      <div>
          <span id="humidity">0</span><span>%</span>
      </div>
</section>
```

location is getting updated after hitting the submit button. But the value of the variable doesn't change. I've already looked around stackoverflow and other sites but didn't find any solution that works for me.

Comment: How are you validating that the value of variable has not changes?

Comment: its properly work whats wrong in this..

Comment: Your code works. what is the issue?

Comment: After page reload again the variable set to  var userInput = "London";

Comment: Don't push the code in comment . just update your question using edit option @DeputyDong_

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code. It's almost certain that you have misdiagnosed the problem – `userInput` changes, but e.g. `url2` doesn't change automatically unless you update it, and the API call doesn't update unless you make it again. Please read [mcve] and post a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Your request will only run on `page load` . you need to run that again after user change the `userInput` .so make it as a function and call it every time of `userInput` change like this .

```js
var userInput = "London";

function changeValue() {
  userInput = document.getElementById("user_Input").value;
  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = document.getElementById("user_Input").value;
  
  ajax_call();
}

function ajax_call(){

var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=";
var units = "&units=metric";
var url2 = api + userInput + units + APPID;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        
        var iconCode = myObj.list[0].weather[0].id;
        var directions = myObj.list[0].deg;

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            
            document.getElementById("day" + i).innerHTML =  Math.round(myObj.list[i].temp.day) + "°";
            document.getElementById("icon" + i).src = "sl_line/" + iconCode + ".svg";
            document.getElementById("wota" + i).innerHTML = wochentag[day.getDay()+i+1];
            document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = Math.round(myObj.list[0].humidity);
            document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = myObj.list[0].speed + " m/s";
            document.getElementById("direction").innerHTML = directions;
        }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url2, true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

window.onload = function() {

    ajax_call();
};
```

```html
<article>
  <input id="user_Input" type="text" placeholder="Ortsuchen...">
  <button id="submit" onclick="changeValue()">Submit</button>
  <span id="location">Unknown</span>
</article>
<section>
      <div>
          <div><span id="day0" class="ml:.25r fs:6r">0</span></div>
          <div><span id="wochentage">0</span></div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <img id="icon0">
      </div>
      <div>
          <span id="wind">0</span><span id="direction"></span><span></span>
      </div>
      <div>
          <span id="humidity">0</span><span>%</span>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user  reference .@DeputyDong_